# How OpenCV's ConnectedComponent algorithm works?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, connected-components

I would like to find the connected components in this image (the image is binary)

[image]

and for that, I use the OpenCV **cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats** algorithm. But the latter gives me a result that I can't understand. Indeed, if we take the first connected component, we find that there are several parts of this component that are not connected (see image, the component is in white).

[image]

Could you explain to me the logic behind this result?

PS 1: I tried with other connected component algorithms (such as skimage.mesure.label) and I got the same results!

PS 2: For comparaison, here's the second connected component (always in white)

[image]

Comment: Hoe are you showing the connected components? You get back a labeled image, where pixels for the fist connected component have a value of 1, those of the second a value of 2, etc. Pixels with a value of 0 are not part of a connected component, they are background pixels, the pixels with a value of 0 in the input. Only foreground pixels are considered by connected component analysis.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your answer, this explain everything, and this is what I have noticed!